# android - geocoder.getfromlocationname returns Service Not Available

Tags: android

I have this wierd bug on my phone (Not Emulator).
I wrote a code a button with edittext of navigating to the first result entered.
It worked for a few days and as I continued devlopibg it suddenly stopped working.
What is wierd is that I installed an earlier version and it didnt work.
The specific code part didnt change since!
Also, I installed the most updated version on a different phone and suddenly it didnt work on it either.
I dont know how to solve it and I dont understand why I get this error.
Why does it suddenly say Service Not Available if it worked before ?
This is the code:

```
configure Search button//Button btn_search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.map_ ;(search_button if(!came_from.matches(" (("FollowLocation } ;(btn_search.setEnabled(false { btn_search.setOnClickListener( } ()new OnClickListener } (public void onClick(View v final AlertDialog.Builder ;(alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context final EditText input = new ;(EditText(context input.setHint("Enter ;("Address input.setImeOptions( ;(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ;(alert.setView(input alert.setPositiveButton("OK", } ()new DialogInterface.OnClickListener public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int } (whichButton String value = ;()input.getText().toString().trim } try Geocoder geocoder =

Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), ;(Locale.ENGLISH List<Address> results

;(geocoder.getFromLocationName(value, 1

} (if (results.size() == 0

AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new ;(AlertDialog.Builder(context

builder2.setMessage("No Address Found, ("Please Try Again

(setCancelable(true.

setNegativeButton("OK", new. } ()DialogInterface.OnClickListener public } (void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id

;()dialog.cancel { ({ ;()show. { else } Address ;(address = results.get(0 GeoPoint p = (new GeoPoint((int address.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)) ;(((address.getLongitude() * 1E6 gMapView = ;((MapView) findViewById(R.id.myGMap mc = ;()gMapView.getController

;(mc.setZoom(18

;(mc.animateTo(p

remove//previous overlays and put this location as circle

;()gMapView.getOverlays().clear Add a //

MyLocationOverlay circleOverlay = new ;()MyLocationOverlay

;circleOverlay.circle=true list = ;()gMapView.getOverlays

;(list.add(circleOverlay {

} (catch (Exception e {

AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new ;(AlertDialog.Builder(context

builder2.setMessage("Error. Please check

(".internet connection

(setCancelable(true.

setNegativeButton("OK", new. } ()DialogInterface.OnClickListener public } (void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id

;()dialog.cancel { ({ ;()show. {

{ ;({ alert.setNegativeButton(" Cancel", new } ()DialogInterface.OnClickListener public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int } (whichButton ;()dialog.cancel { ;({ ;()alert.show { ;({
```

Comment: please paste your code in proper way.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my problem was restarting my phone.

Comment: as much as the answer seems lame, it is the answer none the less. I have ICS ph and JB xoom both throwing exception and restarting them both as answered works.

Comment: That's the eleventh commandment: Thou shalt not know what really happened.